# Starting "asyncExec" in Mouse Down Event results in blocking behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, swt, mouseevent

Having a "next" Button, when I press keyboard enter key with the button selected, the widgetSelected event of the button is being repeatedly called once and once and doing a super fast next. It's exactly the behaviour I want, but only happens with keyboard enter key.

I want to have that behaviour with mouse click when holding the click. When trying to do the same with the mouse click, the behaviour is not the same, it only makes one event call, and when the click is end (UP). How to simulate the same behaviour with the mouse click?

I tried it doing this, but it blocks the UI (can't understand why) **and mouseUp is never being called**, it blocks forever in the `while`:

```
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        boolean mouseDown;
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mouseDown");
            mouseDown = true;
            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (mouseDown) {
                        System.out.println("Doing next in mouseDown");
                        next(composite, label_1);
                        synchronized(this){
                            try {
                                wait(100);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mouseUp");
            mouseDown = false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Start by following the 'blocking' issue. Also, the variable must be `volatile` to ensure it is "seen" between the threads, should there be multiple threads.

Comment: @user2864740 can you post some sample code with your proposal please? can't understand what do you want me to do

Comment: I don't have a proposal other than using `volatile boolean mouseDown` [my preference is to use explicit Threads, but I'm also "old school" like that] :) Hopefully someone will provide useful feedback possible UI-async interactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Runnable` you give to `asyncExec` runs in the UI thread. You must **never** do any sort of wait in the UI thread as that will block the UI until it completes.

So you cannot run a loop like this as it just blocks the UI. Since the loop never returns to the main SWT `readAndDispatch` loop no UI actions are done.

Instead use the `timerExec` method of `Display` to schedule a `Runnable` to run after a given interval. This runnable should do one step of the action and use `timerExec` to schedule the next step later.

Comment: Hi @greg-449 thanks for your idea but how to achieve a bucle of timerExec methods until mouseUp event? If i call a new timerExec inside the original timerExec I'm getting only two calls to my function, and if I do timerExecs allways my funcion is called I'm getting a infinite loops of timerExecs.

Comment: ok @greg-449 I understand you now. You mean using recursive calls of a method which launches timerExec when my mouseDown boolean is true and setting it to false on mouseUp event. It worked using that. Thank you for your great idea :)

Comment: mmmm the problem is that if I'm doing that I'm getting superfast next even with one single click :| mmm I'm sure must be a easy way to solve this...

Comment: well I think I solved it using a new method which tries to start the 100ms method if the boolean is still true after 1 second, the behaviour is similar to what i was expecting so thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I remember there was another question a few days ago regarding a long mouse click behaviour but I can't find it anymore. I put this code based on greg-449 solution to use timerExec method, after my failed attempts to use asyncExec in the UI thread. :)

```
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        boolean mouseDown;

        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDown = true;
            Display.getCurrent().timerExec(1000, () -> {
                if (mouseDown) {
                    button.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, new Event());
                    button.notifyListeners(SWT.MouseDown, new Event());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDown = false;
        }
    });

    button.addSelectionListener(SelectionListener.widgetSelectedAdapter(
            e -> System.out.println("Do next")));
```